# Trouble with std::shuffle on object with member vectors of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a card game, where players have different kinds of cards in their deck. I've implemented this via inheritance(and virtual functions), along with a simple enum class that will help me track what type each card is. All this is background info, and I'm not sure how relevant it is, but I thought I should put it here in any case.

As part of the game(which has an indeterminate number of players >= 2), I first need to shuffle the players(whose decks are passed as vectors of unique pointers to cards to the constructor of the arena class, which is responsible for running the game) for the purpose of randomizing the turn order. When I call std::shuffle on the vector of players, I get template vomit regarding swap being deleted for unique_pointers. However, looking up the Internet tells me that unique_ptrs can very much be shuffled, and my class player is just a group of vectors of unique_ptrs to cards.

If it helps, I'm using GCC 4.8.1(via MinGW-builds).

The relevant code is below(all relevant headers have been included, I'm very sure that that is not the problem):

```
using namespace std;
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
class card {
    string code;
};
class zone {
protected:
    vector<unique_ptr<card>> cards;
public:
    void append(unique_ptr<card>& temp) {
        cards.push_back(move(temp));
    }
//Rest of stuff not relevant
};
class player {
public:
    zone deck;
    zone hand;
    zone discard_pile;
    zone prizes;
    Field playarea;
    player(int field_size, int max_repeat,vector<unique_ptr<card>>& cards,int DECK_SIZE, int prize_count) {
        for (auto it=cards.begin();it!=cards.end();++it)
            deck.append(*it);
        deck.validate(max_repeat); //Implemented in Deck, doesn't have problems
    }
};
class arena {
    vector<player> battlers;
public:
    arena(vector<vector<unique_ptr<card>>>& arr) {
        for (int i=0;i<2;++i) {
            battlers.emplace_back(6,4,arr[i],2,6);
        }
        shuffle(battlers.begin(),battlers.end(),gen);
    }
};
//Providing some vectors which can be passed as dummies from main().
vector<unique_ptr<card>> temp,temp2;
unique_ptr<card> a1= new card;
unique_ptr<card> a2= new card;
unique_ptr<card> a3= new card;
unique_ptr<card> a4= new card;
temp.push_back(move(a1));
temp.push_back(move(a2));
temp2.push_back(move(a3));
temp2.push_back(move(a4));
vector<vector<unique_ptr<card>>> tempo;
tempo.push_back(move(temp));
tempo.push_back(move(temp2));
arena(tempo) arentemp;
```

I've checked the syntax of shuffle, and it appears to be correct. Is there something about unique_ptr that I'm missing here?

(If there is any further info needed, please tell me and I will edit it in.)

EDIT:
The part of the template vomit that I believe is relevant is:

```
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|75|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = card; _Dp = std::default_delete<card>]'|


The template vomit, as requested, in all its wonderful entirety:
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h||In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<card, std::default_delete<card> >&}]':|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|75|required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|117|required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|258|required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|316|required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<card> >]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|143|required from 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = player]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|147|required from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4410|required from 'void std::shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter, _UGenerator&&) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _UGenerator = std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32u, 624u, 397u, 31u, 2567483615u, 11u, 4294967295u, 7u, 2636928640u, 15u, 4022730752u, 18u, 1812433253u>&]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|257|required from here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|75|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = card; _Dp = std::default_delete<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|273|error: declared here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h||In instantiation of 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]':|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|390|required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = const std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|428|required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|460|required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<card>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<card> > >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc|199|required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<card> >]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|143|required from 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = player]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|147|required from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4410|required from 'void std::shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter, _UGenerator&&) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _UGenerator = std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32u, 624u, 397u, 31u, 2567483615u, 11u, 4294967295u, 7u, 2636928640u, 15u, 4022730752u, 18u, 1812433253u>&]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|257|required from here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|335|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = card; _Dp = std::default_delete<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|274|error: declared here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h||In instantiation of 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]':|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|390|required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|428|required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|460|required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _OI = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc|205|required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<card> >]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|143|required from 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = player]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|147|required from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4410|required from 'void std::shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter, _UGenerator&&) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _UGenerator = std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32u, 624u, 397u, 31u, 2567483615u, 11u, 4294967295u, 7u, 2636928640u, 15u, 4022730752u, 18u, 1812433253u>&]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|257|required from here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|335|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = card; _Dp = std::default_delete<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|274|error: declared here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h||In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Args = {std::unique_ptr<card, std::default_delete<card> >&}]':|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|75|required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|117|required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_uninitialized.h|258|required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<card>*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc|209|required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<card>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<card> >]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|143|required from 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = player]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|147|required from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _ForwardIterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4410|required from 'void std::shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter, _UGenerator&&) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<player*, std::vector<player> >; _UGenerator = std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32u, 624u, 397u, 31u, 2567483615u, 11u, 4294967295u, 7u, 2636928640u, 15u, 4022730752u, 18u, 1812433253u>&]'|
D:\NEO TCG FILES\Cards.hpp|257|required from here|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h|75|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = card; _Dp = std::default_delete<card>]'|
d:\c++11\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|273|error: declared here|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 36 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Please narrow down the code to an http://sscce.org, there is way too much irrelevant stuff.

Comment: `shuffle` is trying to `swap` `player`s via copying, which is impossible since `player` has several members that contain a non-copyable `vector<std::unique_ptr<card>>`. You need to determine why `player`'s implicit move constructor is being suppressed - something in there isn't copyable *or* movable.

Comment: `unique_ptr<card> a1= new card;` isn't valid syntax. Can you please provide an SSCCE as requested above instead of just randomly deleting code? Basically that means giving us a code example that we can compile that demonstrates the problem you are having. Otherwise, we will just have to end up guessing, plugging in the holes, and probably have code that doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: [If I fix all the syntax errors in the code you posted it runs fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/144a6b0ad240da49). Please post code that actually reproduces the error.

Comment: @remyabel ^ Casey-in-point. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about `unique_ptr` you are missing, because what fails is shuffling the vector of `player`s, not vector of uniqute pointers.

Either:

- you are shuffling different vector than you wanted to,
- you should have a `vector<unique_ptr<player>> battlers;` or
- you need to specialize `std::swap` for `player`, because the default implementation does not work for some reason. The reason why it does not work **is not shown in the question**.

I suspect you should really be shuffling an array of unique pointers to cards before giving them to the players, but I don't know what you are up to, so I can say for certain.

Comment: `std::swap` works perfectly with move-only types.

Comment: @Casey: You are right. There must be something else that makes `player` non-swappable. And it most probably isn't shown in the question.

Comment: No, I really do need to shuffle the vector of players(each of them has a vector of cards, it's true, but those cards don't need to be shuffled at this point), to randomize the turn ordering. However, when I shuffled it by using unique_ptrs to players, it worked, so thank you!